# Implement Country and Province dropdown list in drupal 7 programmatically using Location module

Tags: api, drupal, user-location

I am implementing a Drupal 7 signup form (through a custom module) where users should be able to  indicate their location (Country + Province/State) using dropdown lists.
From the description of Location module, this seems possible (by using APIs or someother way). I am new to Drupal and have no idea of how to implement this in the custom module programatically (using location module's APIs). I've googled about this for a couple of days, but couldn't make much progress.

Any sample code or leads would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a Ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out how this is done.  We just need to call the api function like here                                               $country = array(location_get_provinces("us"));
 This returns the provinces of the country which is supplied as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If location module provides what you what, you should use it. Otherwise try with address field module.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out how this is done.  We just need to call the api function like here    <pre> <code> $country = array(location_get_provinces("us")); . This returns the provinces of the country which is supplied as a parameter.

Comment: Great! I believe this will do!